# Is there any way to convert pdf file to jpg without imagemagick or ghostscript.?

Tags: php, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to convert pdf files to jpg without use of imagemagick and ghostscript, if anyone have an idea please help me.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use these tools?

Comment: If you cannot use imagemagick and ghostscript then is it because of some restriction or requirement? If so then what are the requirements?

Comment: yes i have a reason that i have no problem with imagemagick but ghostscript encountered an error. so tell me how can i use imagemagick and ghostscript. i new in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an online conversion service instead.

For example [transloadit](https://transloadit.com/) provides an API which can be used to extract images from PDF files (https://transloadit.com/docs/extracting-images-of-documents). They even provide ready development kits for PHP (https://transloadit.com/docs/development-kits#php-sdk).

[Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) could be an alternative as well.

If you instead what to work around the error with ghostscript open another question with detailes for that provided.