# PHP | Convert uploaded PDF into JPG without installing Imagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, converters

Is there a way to use Imagick as some kind of Library?
I want to upload an PDF, which gets converted and saved as JPG.

Without using ghostscript or Imagick as installation. Any kind of Library you know?

I tried the "ilovepdf" - Library, did not worked out well.

Comment: What do you mean by "kind of Library"?

Comment: As far as i know i need to install Imagick on my current PC together with Ghostscript to get it working. 

The Problem is, that i dont need a Program which runs and converts me PDF-Files. I am looking for a libary i can include and use in my project.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594002/is-there-any-way-to-convert-pdf-file-to-jpg-without-imagemagick-or-ghostscript help? Additionally, there are multiple questions with the same requirement on SO

Comment: Yes that helped a bit :)

Comment: Looked at that post and their answer do not go well with my plans...any other ideas? To clearify my question a little bit. I have a form where a user can upload a pdf-file. This File needs to be converted and saved as JPG. Unfortunatly im not seeing Imagick doing this? Isnt Imagick a tool to have it installed on my pc? Or can i use Imagick as PHP Library instead? If so, how?

Comment: Imagick is a library to be installed on your server, and there should be tons of tutorials that tell you how to convert a PDF to a JPG image using Imagick

Comment: As far as i understood its a server extension. That means i need to "upgrade" my server to let it understand the imagick functions and stuff. But thats something different than just including a library with "require_once" right? because im not allowed to install server-sided stuff. So im looking for a way to have a bunch of files with something like a "init.php" which i can call and use the functions of it. Imagick doesnt do that right? or is it just too late for me to work and im not seeing that? ^^

Comment: No, you are right: Imagick is a tool that is distributed as a binary and will not run by simply requiring something. But usually, stuff like this can be installed through your hoster if it is not already

Comment: Thank you, you helped me alot for my understanding while using Imagick. I fixed my problem by looking up my server configs. There is Imagick installed, so my problem and alot of confusion is solved. Thumbs up from my side :)